# How to style blockeditor and frontend together in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

while developing themes, I never really cared about, if the WordPress editor looks similar to the front end. With the implementation of full site editing in 5.9, I would like to change this and see actually something in the block editor that is closer to the frontend look.

Where do you put the different styles? If I would load my full frontend css to the backend as well, it would mess up many things.

Examples:

- I have a drak theme. So the background is black and the font-color
  white. How should I apply this to the backend? Normally I give the
  background settings directly to the whole  and change the font
  using * {font-size: fff;}. Do I need to use more specific classes
  from now on to not have this changes for example in the dashboard as
  well? (Generally I enjoy styling html elements directly, would be a pity to always need to write long class names)
- Until now I also put the custom block styles to my main css file.
  Where they go best?
- Should I do something like a backend blockeditor css, a frontend only
  css and a third file for styles I want to have on both sides?
- I had a little look on to theme.json, but it looks a bit messy to have the full styling of all blocks in there.

I think the direction is clear ;)  How do you approach the styling, what are efficient solutions for this?

Thanks for tips, experiences, links or what ever might be helpful to dissolve my confusions.

Cheers,
Piiit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around for some weeks, here is now my approach:

- General styles for website background, font type and color, are handled by the theme.json.
- Styles for footer, cookienotice, header and everything I don't need to load to the editor are loading over the normal style.css.
- Styles I want on both sides, I put in a seperate editor-style.css and load it over functions.php to front- and back-end. To not run in to troubbles with the general wordpress interface I always adress the blocks directly. So instead of just writing `table` in css, I write `.wp-block-table table`.
- Before I heavily used ACF Plugin to create custom blocks. (Very powerful, but looks pretty unorganized in the editor) Thanks to the new block pattern feature, I could replace almost all ACF Blocks surprisingly easy.

It's a pretty small amount of extra work and incredibly charming to have the editor look more or less exactly like the final website.